# FMOD - Unhandled Exception with no source code avaiable

Tags: c++, fmod

I'm trying to get my audio track to play using FMOD but I keep getting an unhandled exception and then it says there's no source code available, and shows me disassembly code.

```
main.cpp
        bool AudioProject::initAudio()
    {
        // Audio code
        fmSound = new Sound();
        fmSound->initialise();
        fmSound->load("Music/Rocky_Theme_Tune.mp3");
        fmSound->play();
        return true;
    }
```

I put break points in the see where it stopped, which was in the initialise function. It even goes into the initialise function and then just randomly breaks. I think I have every include file for fmod as I used it last year no problem.

I'll post my sound.h/.cpp files too.

.h

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma once
#include "fmod.hpp"
#include "fmod.h"


class Sound
{
private:
    bool on; //is sound on?
    bool possible; //is it possible to play sound?
    char * currentSound; //currently played sound
    //FMOD-specific stuff
    FMOD_RESULT result;
    FMOD_SYSTEM * fmodsystem;
    FMOD_SOUND * sound;
    FMOD_CHANNEL * channel;

public:
    Sound();
    ~Sound();
    void initialise (void); 
    void setVolume (float v); 
    void load (const char * filename); 
    void unload (void);
    void play (bool pause = false); 
    bool getSound (void); 
    void setPause (bool pause); 
    void setSound (bool sound); 
    void toggleSound (void); 
    void togglePause (void); 

};
```

.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Sound.h"
#include "fmod.h"
#include "fmod.hpp"

Sound::Sound()
{
    on = true; //is sound on?
    possible = true; //is it possible to play sound?
    currentSound=""; //currently played sound
    sound=0;

}

Sound::~Sound()
{

}

//initialises sound
void Sound::initialise (void) 
{

    //create the sound system. If fails, sound is set to impossible
    result = FMOD_System_Create(&fmodsystem);
    if (result != FMOD_OK) 
        possible = false;

    //if initialise the sound system. If fails, sound is set to impossible
    if (possible) 
        result = FMOD_System_Init(fmodsystem,2, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0);

    if (result != FMOD_OK) 
        possible = false;

    //sets initial sound volume (mute)
    if (possible) 
        FMOD_Channel_SetVolume(channel,1.0f);
}

//sets the actual playing sound's volume
void Sound::setVolume (float v) 
{
    if (possible && on && v >= 0.0f && v <= 1.0f) 
    {
        FMOD_Channel_SetVolume(channel,v);
    }
}

//loads a soundfile
void Sound::load (const char * filename) 
{
    currentSound = (char *)filename;
    if (possible && on) 
    {
        result = FMOD_Sound_Release(sound);
        result = FMOD_System_CreateStream(fmodsystem,currentSound, FMOD_SOFTWARE, 0, &sound);
        if (result != FMOD_OK) 
            possible = false;
    }
}

//frees the sound object
void Sound::unload (void) 
{
    if (possible) 
    {
        result = FMOD_Sound_Release(sound);
    }
}

//plays a sound (no argument to leave pause as dafault)
void Sound::play (bool pause) 
{
    if (possible && on) 
    {
        result = FMOD_System_PlaySound(fmodsystem,FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, sound, pause, &channel);
        FMOD_Channel_SetMode(channel,FMOD_LOOP_NORMAL);
    }
}

//toggles sound on and off
void Sound::toggleSound (void) 
{
    on = !on;
    if (on == true) 
    { 
        load(currentSound); 
        play(); 
    }
    if (on == false) 
    { 
        unload(); 
    }
}

//pause or unpause the sound
void Sound::setPause (bool pause) 
{
    FMOD_Channel_SetPaused (channel, pause);
}

//turn sound on or off
void Sound::setSound (bool s) 
{
    on = s;
}

//toggle pause on and off
void Sound::togglePause (void) 
{
    FMOD_BOOL p;
    FMOD_Channel_GetPaused(channel,&p);
    FMOD_Channel_SetPaused (channel,!p);
}

//tells whether the sound is on or off
bool Sound::getSound (void) 
{
    return on;
}
```

Hit a brick wall here, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `FMOD_Channel_SetVolume(channel,1.0f)` in `initialise`, but the `channel` variable isn't hasn't been initialized yet, it gets initialized by the `FMOD_System_PlaySound(fmodsystem,FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, sound, pause, &channel);` in `Sound::play`

Comment: It never reaches that line of code, it breaks on the second line into the Sound::initialise function. after the result = FMOD_System_Create(&fmodsystem);